# Signing APK - Is the key alias the private key?

Tags: android, apk, keystore

Is the key alias the name of the private key stored in the key-store, or am I going insane? What is a key alias? Do you use one key-store to store all private keys that correspond to the public key with the apk? can you re-use private keys? Help...

Answer (score 1):

You have a key store (the file, usually with extension .jks or .keystore), and within that you have:

- The keystore password (lets you access anything in the keystore)
- The keys

  - Each key has an alias (it's name) and a password (the key
    password)

So to sign an app, you'll need 2 passwords - that of the keystore, and that of the key/alias.

Comment: OK, that clarifies a lot. So, the key alias is just the name of the key. I understand now thank you :D

Comment: Also, do you use a different key/alias for each apk that you sign?